# How can I change the login time cookie in a password protected page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I know its usually set up for 10 days and would like it to be about 15 minutes.  I've seen a lot of answers on the internet about a certain wp-pass file but it appears that the file doesn't exist anymore in wordpress 3.5

Would anyone know how to change this ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if your using the latest wordpress you can use the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter. something like this would do it:

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', function($expiration){
    return 900; /*15 minutes*/
});
```

You'd have to add that to a plugin.